# Unable to send this number a text message

Tags: android, ios, twitter-digits

We are using Digits for SMS autenthication, and have started receiving notes from some users that they get an error message "Unable to send this number a text message". (this despite the number being a valid cell phone number) The common denominator seems to be that they operate with the same telecom operator in Norway (Telia). I saw a similar post for a carrier in Lebanon so wonder if the same would apply here, more importantly, what can we do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is something about permissions, some of them needs to be asked to the user while their are using the app, read contacts for example.
If that is the problem, i can put here the solution i have to ask the user if he allow the app to use some functions.
If not, i cant help with that mobile company problem.